# gps.conf file is not present

Tags: android, gps

I am using android 2.0 emulator. logcat says:

```
Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
```

I checked everywhere, its not present.
Can you tell me what I should do?
Can you also tell me how to get latitude and longitude in logcat?

One more thing.
The geo fix command stores the latitude and longitude. Can you tell me where they are stored in the emulator (I mean mydroid folder) and how can I retrieve those values using adb shell.
The folder "location" at location /data/misc/location is not present. I created it and a subfolder named gps also in it. But no changes are made to it or no files are written in it by the emulator.
I only want to use adb shell, no java.